# When exactly does SLURM export environmental variables?

Tags: slurm, hpc

With the option `--export=ALL`, the current environmental variables should be visible to the job script when submitted as

```
sbatch --export=ALL jobscript.sh
```

My question is, when exactly does SLURM do the export? Does the export happen when the job is submitted or when it actually starts running? If the job spends some time in the queue and the environmental variables are changed after the job submission but before running starts, which version of them will be "seen" by the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job will see the environment as it is at the time the `sbatch` command is run.

When `sbatch` is run, Slurm will save the environment in a file named `hash.<last digit of the job>/job.<jobid>/environmnet` in the directory configured as `StateSaveLocation`.